# Is there a generalization of a Bernoulli distribution with respect to $p$'s dimension?

Tags: distributions, bernoulli-distribution

When $X\sim Ber(p)$ then $P({X=1})=p$ and the complement's event probability is $1-p$. What if I want to distinguish between $n$ possible events? I will need $n-1$ variables to describe this, right? I know the binomial is a sequence of bernoullis, but this doesn't modify the possible outcomes succes and failure. Sorry if this is naive or stupid, but what do I call this distribution I am looking for?

Comment: Do you mean a [multinomial distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with $n=1$?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should I delete the question? It is rather basic, I just needed a quick hint.

Comment: I think it is ok to keep it as long as it is not a duplicate of another question.